# How to convert a bunch of primitive value types to byte array efficiently in .NET in Silverlight compatible manner?

Tags: .net, serialization

Observe the following .NET type:

```
public class X
{
  public DateTime Timestamp {get;set;}
  public double Value {get;set;}
  public double Min {get;set;}
  public double Max {get;set;}
}
```

I need to convert an array of N elements of X to a single byte array and vice versa efficiently and the code must be Silverlight compatible (meaning forget about the binary serialization, be it efficient or not).

My solution is:

```
public void GetState(SerializationInfo info)
{
  var stream = new MemoryStream();
  var buf = BitConverter.GetBytes(Count);
  stream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
  foreach (var item in this)
  {
    buf = BitConverter.GetBytes(item.Timestamp.Ticks);
    stream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
    buf = BitConverter.GetBytes(item.Value);
    stream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
    buf = BitConverter.GetBytes(item.Min);
    stream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
    buf = BitConverter.GetBytes(item.Max);
    stream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
  }
  info.AddValue("Data", stream.ToArray());
}
public void SetState(SerializationInfo info)
{
  var data = info.GetValue<byte[]>("Data");
  int count = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0);
  Capacity = count;
  int offset = sizeof(int);
  while (count-- > 0)
  {
    Add(new ExtendedNormalizedSample(
      new DateTime(BitConverter.ToInt64(data, offset)),
      BitConverter.ToDouble(data, offset += sizeof(long)),
      BitConverter.ToDouble(data, offset += sizeof(double)),
      BitConverter.ToDouble(data, offset += sizeof(double))));
    offset += sizeof(double);
  }
}
```

(Ignore the SerializationInfo stuff - irrelevant for the question)

Anyway, what I do not like about my solution is the abundance of byte[] arrays created during the serialization. I mean, every call to `BitConverter.GetBytes` returns a new byte array and although, creating new byte arrays is cheap in .NET, but still, as a former C++ developer, this seems to be an awful waste to use a new byte array each time, whereas a single byte array can be reused.

Can anyone suggest a better solution (remember, it must be Silverlight compatible, so do not propose unsafe code).

Thanks.

Comment: Side note: you might also want to consider an alternative serializer such as protobuf-net; then no need to do all your own encoding, pretty darned fast (esp. when v2 ships, as this helps SL a lot), and very small output. Plus: free.

Comment: I need to make a fast change now, but I always keep protobuf-net in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DateTime` `Ticks` could be encoded as an integer via shift operations etc. The `float` - you *might* try using a union to swap for `int`, and then encode the `int` with shift operations:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct MyUnion
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    private int i;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    private float f;

    public static int ToInt32(float value) {
        MyUnion u = new MyUnion();
        u.f = value;
        return u.i;
    }
    public static float ToSingle(int value) {
        MyUnion u = new MyUnion();
        u.i = value;
        return u.f;
    }
}
```

Then if you have an existing `Stream` or `byte[]` you can encode (depending on your chosen endianness) something like:

```
int iValue = MyUnion.ToInt32(fValue);


int offset = ...;
...
buffer[offset++] = (byte)iValue;
buffer[offset++] = (byte)(iValue >> 8);
buffer[offset++] = (byte)(iValue >> 16);
buffer[offset++] = (byte)(iValue >> 24);
```

Comment: But I have a double, not float. So, it must be long rather than int.

Comment: I guess, it does not matter - the principal stays the same. Thanks.

Comment: @Mark - indeed; subst for `long` in that case